# Warning in traversing Pandas DataFrame index: Expected type 'int', got 'Hashable' instead

Tags: python, pandas

I have a piece of code like:

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index == 0:
            continue
        elif df.loc[df.index[index], 'date'] == df.loc[df.index[index - 1], 'date']:
            df.loc[df.index[index], 'desc'] = 'same date'
```

This code works. However, IDE (PyCharm) warns me that in `[index - 1]`, `index` is a Hashable not an Int which is expected. This typing warning makes sense because `.iterrows()` returns `index` as a Hashable but we are doing integer operation here. The question is, how to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to avoid the warning, this works on my system:

```
if int(str(index)) == 0:
```

But, that's entirely unnecessary.  iterrows() doesn't preserve dtypes across rows so it just looks like a hashable object (to PyCharm) even though Python correctly identifies it as an integer when using type() to gets its type.  The important thing is that Python recognizes it as Int even if PyCharm doesn't.You can either change your code or just ignore it if you feel secure with the dtype.

Verify it's just PyCharm and not Python by using the type() function.

```
print(type(index))
```

That should return:

```
<class 'int'>
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

iterrows is rarely the best way to solve a problem like this.  You can shift the entire date row and check if the previous date is equal to the current date all in one operation.  Just like your example index 0 will always be nan because there is no prior date for the first index when shifting dates forward.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['10-10-22','10-11-22','10-12-22','10-12-22','10-13-22']})

df.loc[df.date.shift().eq(df.date), 'desc'] = 'same date'
```

Output

```
       date       desc
0  10-10-22        NaN
1  10-11-22        NaN
2  10-12-22        NaN
3  10-12-22  same date
4  10-13-22        NaN
```